# sidenav generates drawer already declared for end

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<mat-card class="settings-panel">
  <mat-card-title>
    Settings
  </mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-sidenav-container class="settings-container">
      <mat-sidenav #sides align="end" class="settings-sidenav" mode="side">
        <app-sides></app-sides>
      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav #toppings align="end" class="settings-sidenav" mode="side">
        <app-toppings></app-toppings>
      </mat-sidenav>

      <div class="settings-sidenav-content">
        <button type="button" mat-button (click)="sides.open()">
          Sides
        </button>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" mat-button (click)="toppings.open()">
          Toppings
        </button>
      </div>

    </mat-sidenav-container>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

And it appears to be working, but there's an error in the web console:

```
Error: A drawer was already declared for 'position'="end"
```

This makes me think I'm abusing the control, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared mat-sidnav twice on the same side. Stick to one, or assign second 
 to other side `align="start"`

```
 <mat-sidenav #sides align="end" class="settings-sidenav" mode="side">
    <app-sides></app-sides>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav #toppings align="start" class="settings-sidenav" mode="side">
    <app-toppings></app-toppings>
  </mat-sidenav>
```

If you're really trying to create dynamic side nav on same side, you can try to get away with two sidenav-containers or render using `ngIf` or route to modify which component it shows

Side note, align is deprecated, it's position now.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the info.  Two sidenav-containers is the strategy that worked to allow two(2) <mat-sidenav position="start">.

More info from Angular can be found here: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#troubleshooting